# Write metadata to an audio file

Tags: android

Is there anyway to write metadata to an audio file? The web is full of stuff on MediaMetadataRetriever but not editing. I've looked at [MetadataEditor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/RemoteControlClient.MetadataEditor.html) but that doesn't seem to let me write metadata to a specific file. Pretty much I want to add a Bitmap to an audio file so that when a 3rd party app plays the audio file it has cover art. Thanks :)

Comment: You'll probably want to look around for **ID3 tag** in combination with Android/Java. Afaik there is nothing built in the Android SDK, but I'm sure there are various generic Java libraries out there that will do the job just fine on Android devices (read: these are just `File` operations and there shouldn't be anything Android-specific about them).

Comment: isn't ID3 only for mp3? I'm not using mp3s.

Comment: My bad. I read 'audio file' and assumed you were talking about mp3. I'm not aware of any standardized metadata container for audio files in general. I suppose actual support will be up to the specific file formats we're talking about.

Comment: Just to make sure I'm on the right path here, I want my audio to be scanned by MediaScanner and picked up by the "Play Music" app and have an album cover. I'm assuming this is done with metadata but I could be wrong. Thoughts?

Comment: In that case you should work with the `MediaStore`. Cover art is stored on a per-album basis in [`MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM_ART`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Audio.AlbumColumns.html#ALBUM_ART). A basic approach would be to populate that column with the cover's file location (as `file://` `Uri`), but if you're feeling fancy, you can also write you own `ContentProvider`. There's quite a bit of documentation and there should be plenty of examples, so I'd recommend searching around a bit using these keywords.

Comment: I've done a simple test of just adding an album to the sdcard and allowing MediaScanner to run again. The album information (track names, album cover, dates) is purely based upon the metadata are not the MediaStore. I've even looked at the MediaStore database and that information does not exist in there. So my thoughts are confirmed. Now it's just a matter of editing the metadata.